Does the ZX Spectrum's system variable PROG always hold 23755 (5CCBh)?
At the ZX Spectrum, the system variable PROG (23635) contains the start of the BASIC program (see the manual). At my ZX Spectrum when I do
PRINT PEEK(23635) + 256 * PEEK(23636)

I get 23755. So a BASIC program starts at 23755.
My question is:

Is it always 23755 on all spectrum models?
Does it depend on if a microdrive and/or printer is attached?

E.g. see here. The memory map there suggests that 'microdrive maps' and 'Channel information' might have flexible lengths, thus changing the address held in PROG.
I am asking to simplify my project.

If PROG were a constant, it would likely not reside in the variable area, wouldn't it? :)

@tofro - Oh, I dunno.  But then I program in Java, a language which has 'constant variables'.

@Dave That might be it, then. But no, the Spectrum didn't have such fancy stuff.

Typo in your title: "Is" or "If"?

@tofro - my comment was meant as just highlighting the sometimes loose connection between words programmers use and their actual meaning.

The only example of moving PROG I know about is when you're using TR-DOS disk system. There, once the TR-DOS is initialized, PROG goes to $5D40 if I remember that correctly. But this is obviously not your concern here hence you're doing TAPE turboloader.

Starting from the channel information area (which is pointed to by the CHANS system variable), the ZX Spectrum memory map is moving because of variable lengths of specific dedicated memory areas.

First of all, the length of the "Microdrive maps" area (starting at 23734) is variable (from zero, with no IF 1 fitted, to 8 * 594 bytes with 8 connected drives), because Interface I (and various other add-ons like floppy interfaces that need their own variables) tend to extend this area upwards, and obviously everything beyond this area needs to move up as well.
Second, opening and closing channels in the area pointed to CHANS will move the beginning of BASIC (thus, what PROG points to) up and down. Channels can be opened at the programmers will, but most likely that will be done to microdrive, serial and network ports, because the channels to the in-built peripherals (#1, #2, #3) are per default already open and their memory allocated.
All of the above makes the BASIC program move up or down in memory and thus changes the contents of PROG that points to it.
There are also a lot of "tricks" that can be used on an unexpanded ZX Spectrum to hide a BASIC program (for copy protection purposes, for example) from the user by tampering with PROG. With such programs loaded, PROG will obviously not have the expected value.
You will likely have realized that all of the above will also affect machine code programs stored in a REM statement (they move as well, obviously). That is why the ZX manual advises not to put machine code programs into REM statements (but rather above RAMTOP).
Connecting or disconnecting a ZX printer doesn't change PROG, because the printer buffer is statically allocated on the 48K model and not present in 128k mode at all.
It should be a minor problem, however, to acquire the value of PROG from the system variable area instead of assuming a constant.

Thanks, but does that mean that when the ZX Spectrum is just powered on (nobody added channels yet) and has no microdrive attached, PROG is actually always 23755? What about different ZX spectrum models? I have only one to test!

A "naked" ZX Spectrum will always have PROG at its default address when switched on. This is true even if an interface I is present (can't say for other disk systems, though).  This is also true for the 128k models, at least in 48k mode. I do, however, not quite understand why you wouldn't want to invest that single instruction needed to retrieve the value.

I am writing a turboloader, and because speed is the goal, I can load only one block with the ROM loader, which has to be basic, therefore all machine code is in a REM statement. So it all has to be re-locatable (jr instead of jp, cant use call etc). (Although part of it is copied to the top 32K (non-contended) memory). Btw I just now realized my CLEAR statement is really 'tight' so if PROG is anything above 23755 it wont work anyway...

Opening the three built-in channels (all you can do without an interface) doesn't alter the size of CHANS.

@neil That's what this answer it's saying (third paragraph) -- They are open (and allocated) per default.

Ah, I was unclear as to what you meant by that.

I've tested 48K and 128K models and this i what I found:
If Interface 1 is fitted, at power-on boot -- or after a NEW -- PROG system variable contains 23755.
The first time a peculiar Interface 1 BASIC command is invoked, then PROG
is added some 58 bytes (the system variables needed by Interface 1) moving the Basic Program area upward, even if no channel is OPEN#ed yet.
For example, at power-on, CLEAR # changes PROG to 23813, but also STOP does it or any other non-ok error message.
On the other hand, you can repeatedly give PRINT getting 0 OK, 0:1 message and PROG won't move, but the first "real" error message will.
